# Creating a new list from the data in the list with certain rules

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have data from different csv files. These data are listed and include VAT 0 and total amounts. Apart from these two information, many other values are also present in my list. In the example, my total amount is 4000 and VAT is 0. According to my algorithm, it replaces 4000 with the largest and possibly irrelevant value. df=[26300.0, 17360.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 4000.0, 6.575, 3.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] The important point is that the lists vary. Example from my shared list unittest.

```
def zero_vat(df):
    catch_list=[]
    df.sort(reverse = True)
    print(df)
    for i, value in enumerate(df):  # 1.array
        for j, value2 in enumerate(df):  # 2.array
            if df[i]==0:
                if df[i]+max(df)==df[j]:
                    temp_list=[]
                    temp_list.append(df[i])
                    temp_list.append(df[j])
                    temp_list.append(max(df))
                    catch_list.append(temp_list)
                    print(catch_list)
            elif df[i]+0 == max(df):
                temp_list=[]
                temp_list.append(df[i])
                temp_list.append(0.0)
                temp_list.append(max(df))
                catch_list.append(temp_list)
                print(catch_list)
            return catch_list
```

output : [[26300.0, 0.0, 26300.0]]
must be :[[4000.0,0.0,4.000]]

Comment: Just for clarity, are you saying you obtain "[[26300.0, 0.0, 26300.0]] ", but were expecting "[[4000.0,0.0,4.000]]"?

Comment: Yeah. lists have 0 exact and one of the other elements totals. amount in this list is 4000.00. with my code the oldest one chooses 26300.00

Comment: The catch_list is returned for i = 0 and j = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a function that takes the odd and large numbers in my list.

```
   def find_largest_duplicated_value(df):
        duplicated_values = []

        for item in df:
            if df.count(item) > 1:
               duplicated_values.append(item)

        return max(duplicated_values)
```